# WooCommerce: product attribute tax query issue, not showing any products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

In Woocommerce, I am trying to query products via a WP_Query, that have specific product attributes depending on the displayed page.

The following code is not showing any products:

```
<div class="container py-5">
  <div class="row">
    <?php
    $postid = get_the_ID();
    if ($postid == 48) {
      $sect = 'veiw';
    } elseif ($postid == 148) {
      $sect = 'wall';
    } elseif ($postid == 192) {
      $sect = 'pasio';
    } elseif ($postid == 146) {
      $sect = 'floor';
    } elseif ($postid == 147) {
      $sect = Stairs;
    }
    $query = new WP_Query(array(
      'post_type'      =>
      'product', 'post_status' => 'publish', 
      'posts_per_page' => -1, 'tax_query'
      => array(array(
        'taxonomy' => 'pa_usage', 
        'terms' => explode(",", $sect),
        'field' => 'slug', 
        'operator' => 'IN'
      ))
    ));
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
      echo '
    <div class="col-md-3 productgroup text-right pb-4">
      <li>
        <a href="' . get_permalink() . '"
          ><div class="product__preview">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="' . get_the_post_thumbnail_url() . '" />
          </div>
          <span>' . get_the_title() . '</span></a
        >
      </li>
    </div>
    ';
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I am doing wrong? Any help?

Comment: Note that `$sect = Stairs;`should required to be instead `$sect = 'stairs';`…

Comment: What I am doing wrong? Any help?

Comment: I have not answer your question so that means that I don't know…

Comment: I understand problem : delete 'field' => 'slug',  of code